# Get all possible clusterings in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, combinations

Lets say i have a vector `n = 1:4`.

I want to create a cell array of cells containing all possible groupings of these items, assuming the groupings can be of any size, there can be any number of groups, but each value must be present within each configuration.

Here is an example of what i'd like to create, but without each possibility:

```
possibilities = {
    {[1 2 3 4]},...
    {[1 2 3], 4},...
    {[1 2 4], 3},...
    ...
    {[1 3], [2 4]},...
    ...
    {[1 3], 2, 4},...
    {1,2,3,4}
    }
```

So each cell within the cell contains the values 1:4, but they can be grouped arbitrarily into groups of any size. The only constraint is that each unique clustering should appear only once, where `{[1 2 3], 4}` is identical to `{[2 1 3], 4}` and `{4, [3 1 2]}`.

I think the `nchoosek` function may be of use, but honestly i'm puzzled about how to put it all together in a reasonably elegant way.

Comment: If you look on File Exchange, I'm sure you can find something that will do a set partition.

Comment: This one even uses your test case as its example in its docs: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24185-partitions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1011724/dan) pointed me to [exactly what i wanted](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24185-partitions)...

For the sake of posting the answer with the question, here's how it works.

```
>> possibilities = partitions(4)

possibilities = 

    {1x1 cell}
    {1x2 cell}
    {1x2 cell}
    {1x2 cell}
    {1x3 cell}
    {1x2 cell}
    {1x2 cell}
    {1x3 cell}
    {1x2 cell}
    {1x2 cell}
    {1x3 cell}
    {1x3 cell}
    {1x3 cell}
    {1x3 cell}
    {1x4 cell}

>> partdisp(possibilities)

The 15 partitions of set {1 2 3 4}:
{1 2 3 4} 
{1 2 3} {4} 
{1 2 4} {3} 
{1 2} {3 4} 
{1 2} {3} {4} 
{1 3 4} {2} 
{1 3} {2 4} 
{1 3} {2} {4} 
{1 4} {2 3} 
{1} {2 3 4} 
{1} {2 3} {4} 
{1 4} {2} {3} 
{1} {2 4} {3} 
{1} {2} {3 4} 
{1} {2} {3} {4}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `combnk`:

```
a = 1:4;
for k = 1:length(a) 
    C{k} = combnk(a,k); 
end
```

I think the mathematical concept is called *power set*. Note that the above example misses the empy set.

Comment: I considered something along those lines, but `combnk` does not fill out the clusters so that all items are used. For example `{[1 2 3]}` is not valid, as it lacks `4`

Comment: You're right. You could probably obtain it via a `setdiff` on every line on every matrix in the C{k} with `1:4`. As is my solution is **not valid**.